# Does the Ring of Ancestral Blood Magic work woth the spell applied when starting a greater bloodrage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, class-feature

The [Ring of Ancestral Blood Magic](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MagicRingsDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Ring%20of%20Ancestral%20Blood%20Magic) allows to cast bloodline bonus spells without expending a slot while bloodraging.

> Greater Bloodrage (Su): At 11th level, when a bloodrager enters a bloodrage, the morale bonus to his Strength and Constitution increases to +6 and the morale bonus on his Will saves increases to +3. **In addition, upon entering a bloodrage, the bloodrager can apply the effects a bloodrager spell he knows of 2nd level or lower to himself.** The spell must have a range of touch or personal. If the spell’s duration is greater than 1 round, it instead lasts for the duration of the bloodrage. **This use consumes a bloodrager spell slot, as if he had cast the spell;** he must have the spell slot available to take advantage of this effect.

If I start a greater bloodrage and want to apply a bonus spell to myself, does the ring work?

I am not sure because of two things. First I am not casting the spell normally and second the spell is used at the momen the bloodrage starts and that might cause a conflict with "While the wearer is bloodraging".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring only affects spells the wearer casts, and using a spell slot at the beginning of a bloodrage to benefit from it is not actually casting it. Then the ring has no effect on it and the spell slot is used no matter what.